# SQL Constrain para que inserte la fecha actual en la columna pero sale 1900-01-01

Tags: sql-server

Cuando quiero insertar un alumno quiero que con el constrain inserte la fecha actual de forma automatica en Fecha-Matricula.

```
ALTER table TB_ALUMNO
ADD CONSTRAIT FECH_MATRI_ALU DEFAULT GETDATE() 
FOR FECH_MATRI_ALU
GO
```

Me sale 1900-01-01 en ves de la fecha actual en la columna

Comment: Intenta cambiando el nombre del constraint.

Comment: De que tipo de dato es esa columna en la base de datos?

Comment: Prueba a cambiarlo por `SYSDATETIME()`, por ejemplo: **`ALTER table TB_ALUMNO
ADD CONSTRAIT FECH_MATRI_ALU DEFAULT SYSDATETIME() 
FOR FECH_MATRI_ALU
GO`**

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tienes algunos errores de sintaxis, debería ser de la siguiente manera:

```
alter table NombreDeTuTabla
add constraint NombreDelConstraint default getdate() 
for NombreDelCampo
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Como dijo @José hay errores de sintaxis en tu código.

Sin embargo, creo que lo más conveniente es insertarlo con un trigger

```
create trigger MyTrigger on TB_ALUMNO for insert as 
update TB_ALUMNO set FECH_MATRI_ALU = GETDATE()
```

Debido a que los `constraint`, como su definición en inglés explica, tienen el propósito de limitar (índices, checks, etc) no de escritura ni lectura (como sí lo tienen los triggers).